# C++ Linked List Iterator Class

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I created a singly linked list for a project and now need to create a custom Iterator class. I have a nested class within my Linked List that defines my iterator. I have written most of the class, but am confused as to how to implement some functions. My issues are as follows:

-Please look at my end() function. I set it to the default constructor for the Iterator class, so the 
currentNode variable in iterator got defaulted to NULL I guess. Is this correctly implemented?

-How should I overload the -> operator in the Iterator class?

```
class SSLL_Iter : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T>
    {
    public:
        typedef T value_type;
        typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
        typedef T& reference;
        typedef T* pointer;
        typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
        typedef SSLL_Iter self_type;
        typedef SSLL_Iter& self_reference;

    private:
        Node* currentNode;

    public:
        explicit SSLL_Iter( Node* start = NULL) : currentNode( start ) {}   //****************complete

        SSLL_Iter( const SSLL_Iter& src ) : currentNode( src.currentNode ) {}      //****************complete

        reference operator*() const {   //****************complete
            T& temp = (currentNode->data);
            return temp;
        }

        pointer operator->() const {}  //*******??????????????????

        self_reference operator=( const SSLL_Iter& src ) {     //****************complete

            this->here = src.here;
            return *this;
        }

        self_reference operator++() { // preincrement         //****************complete
            currentNode = currentNode->next;
            return *this;
        }
        self_type operator++(int) {  // postincrement         //****************complete
            self_type temp = (*this);
            ++(*this);
            return temp;
        }

        bool operator==(const SSLL_Iter& rhs) const {        //****************complete
            return (this->currentNode == rhs.currentNode);
        }

        bool operator!=(const SSLL_Iter& rhs) const {        //****************complete
            return (this->currentNode != rhs.currentNode);
        }
    }; // end SSLL_Iter

    typedef std::size_t size_t;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef SSLL_Iter iterator;
    //typedef Const_SSL_Iter const_iterator;

    SSLL() {}

    SSLL(const SSLL& src ) {

        for(int i = 0; i < src.size(); ++i) {    // populate this SSLL with copies of the other SSLL's    contents
            this->push_back(src.item_at(i));
        }
    }

    ~SSLL() {

        if(!is_empty()) {
            clear();
        }

    }

    iterator begin() { return SSLL_Iter( head ); }

    iterator end() { return SSLL_Iter(); }
```

Comment: You can take a look at how a real-life iterator is implemented by opening the `<list>` header and searching.  BTW, your `SSLL` class lacks an assignment operator, unless you didn't post it.

Comment: Thanks. I have the assignment operator though. Where can I access the <list> header?

Comment: If you have a good editor, just `#include <list>`, hover your mouse over the <list>, right-click and choose to open the file (real lazy, but it is effective).  If you don't have such a code editor, then <list> should be in your compiler's directory that contains the standard `include` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return &*(*this);` is a decent `operator->`.

Your `SSLL` class probably does not have an efficient `at`, so don't use it in the copy constructor.  Instead, create a `SSLL` `template<class Iterator> void append(Iterator s, Iterator f)`, and implement `SSLL(const SSLL& src)` in terms of it.

If you have C++11 support, consider replacing the `next` node of `Node` with a `std::unique_ptr<Node>`.  Do the same with the pointer-to-first `Node` in the `SSLL` root.  Now memory management is handled pretty much automatically.  You may need a `.get()` in your iterator after that change.  This also eliminates the body of your destructor, makes your move-constructor `=default` correct (unless you are counting nodes), etc.

Comment: Can you explain what the -> operator does please? Whats the different between that and returning *this, &this, or what you proposed? And great idea with the unique_ptr, but this is a data structs and algorithms class and the entire purpose of this project is handling memory. I would love to use those but I doubt my Prof. would be thrilled :)

Comment: @user3758295 - Creating iterator classes sounds more like "Advanced C++ and Techniques" than "Data Structures".

Comment: @user3758295 There was MUCH more to the project than just the iterator class. This was just one of the specifications.

Comment: @user37558295 it calls `operator*`.  The  returns a pointer to the result.  Technically it should return the address of the result of `operator*`, in case of `&` beimg overloaded.  And using smart pointers is the right way to manage memory in C++11: follow the rule of zero.